# coq Basics: bin_to_nat function

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am passing Logical Foundations course and became stuck upon the last excersize of Basics:

Having binary number write a converter to it's unary representation:

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | Z
  | A (n : bin)
  | B (n : bin).

Fixpoint bin_to_nat (m:bin) : nat :=
  (* What to do here? *)
```

I solved the problem with a recursive function in C. The only thing, I used "0" istead of "A" and "1" instead of "B".

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int pow2(unsigned int power)
{
    if(power != 0)
        return 2 << (power - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}

void rec_converter(char str[], size_t i)
{
    if(str[i] == 'Z')
        printf("%c", 'Z');
    else if(str[i] == '0')
        rec_converter(str, ++i);
    else if(str[i] == '1')
    {
        unsigned int n = pow2(i);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", 'S');
        }
        rec_converter(str, ++i);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "11Z";

    rec_converter(str, 0);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My problem now is how to write this code in coq:

```
unsigned int n = pow2(i);

for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    printf("%c", 'S');
}
rec_converter(str, ++i);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between your code and the Coq code is that the Coq code ought to *return* the natural number, rather than printing it. That means we'll need to keep track of everything that your solution printed and return the result all at once.

Since printing an `S` means that the answer is the successor of whatever else is printed, we'll need a function that can take the 2^(n)th successor of a natural number. There are various ways to do this, but I'd suggest recursion on n and noting that the 2^(n + 1)th successor of x is the 2^(n)th successor of the 2^(n)th successor of x.

That should be enough to get what you want.

```
unsigned int n = pow2(i);

for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    printf("%c", 'S');
}
rec_converter(str, ++i);
```

can be written (in pseudo-Coq) as

```
pow2_succ i (rec_converter str (S i)).
```

However, one other thing to note: you may not be able to directly access the ith "character" of the input, but this shouldn't be a problem. When you write your function as a `Fixpoint`

```
Fixpoint rec_converter (n: bin) (i: nat): nat :=
match n with
| Z => 0
| A m => ...
| B m => ...
end.
```

the first "character" of m will be the second "character" of the original input. So you'll just need to access the first "character", which is exactly what a `Fixpoint` does.

Comment: It is too bad that this answer basically gives the answer to an S.F. exercise.

Comment: Yes, Software Foundations explicitly request _[Please do not post solutions to the exercises in a public place.](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Preface.html#lab10)_

Comment: @Yves (and larsr) I've edited that part out. Though I'll note that that link is directed at "readers" and I've never read any of Software Foundation's material. I based my approach on the Coq standard library.

Comment: @user.  Great, your answer now incorporates the explanation I was trying to add.  I will delete my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the question on computing powers of 2, you should look at the following file, provided in the Coq libraries (at least up to version 8.9):

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Nat.html

This file contains a host of functions around the natural numbers, they could all be used as illustrations about how to program with Coq and this datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fixpoint bin_to_nat (m:bin) : nat :=
  match m with
  | Z => O
  | A n =>2 * (bin_to_nat n)
  | B n =>2 * (bin_to_nat n) + 1
  end.
```

see: coq art's 2004. P167-P168.  ( How to understand 'positive' type in Coq)